# Handling PDF files and In App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have searched alot and im not sure what is the best practice to do, so i ask in here.

I have an app where its possible to make a In App purchase to buy some PDF books. 
The books are just copied into the resources folder in my project.

As i understand, it is possible to unzip the IPA and then get access to the PDF files if they are in my resources folder - so where should i else store them?

I read multiple post about the documents folder, but some say that its only to user generated documents and apple will reject if the files are to big. (im aware that is possible to set the donotbackup)

So i want to be able to save the path for a given PDF book, and make sure that it only can be seen if it is bought (via an attribute on a Entity in core data) :).

Anyone have any ideas what to do? :)